# Javascript not working in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to Android Studio, and have run into a problem that I can't fix.

I'm trying to run a HTML file in a webView, but for some reason it keeps reloading to my startpage/index file, when I try to call specific HTML that includes a specific JS file.

Note: these files work fine in every desktop and mobile browser, and works on UIWebView in an Apple App.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
MyWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
MyWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())
MyWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MyWeb.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
MyWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
MyWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
MyWeb.loadUrl("URL");
```

If I remove the "MyWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())" part, the file works, but the app launches a browser with an address bar.

Please help - I've allready spend more days trying to fix this, than I care to admit.

Comment: I actually had a similar issue but your code was better than mine and after trying yours, app worked fine! Thanks, hopefully you fixed your issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already enabled necessary settings, try doing this once:

```
MyWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
      }
    });

    MyWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to not launch in a browser you must add the line

`MyWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`